# puppet master not signing client certificate

Tags: puppet

`puppet cert --list` does not return anything.

My `/etc/hosts` file on both puppet master and client:

```
20.201.110.198 client.example.com client
20.201.110.196 puppet.example.com puppet
```

While starting puppet master, I get the following,

The version of puppet master is **2.7.25**

```
#puppet master --no-daemonize --debug --verbose
info: Could not find certificate for 'client.example.com'
```

While starting puppet client, I get the following (Puppet client version is also **2.7.25**)

```
puppet agent --server puppet --waitforcert 60 --test --debug  --verbose
notice: Did not receive certificate
```

Comment: On the agent machine, what is the output of `puppet agent --configprint server`? - It also appears that your `master` node thinks its name is `client.example.com`. What is the output of `facter fqdn` on that machine?

Comment: `puppet cert list --all`

Comment: In puppet master server : #puppetca --sign client.example.com
err: Could not call sign: Could not find certificate request for client.example.com
Could not find certificate request for client.example.com

Comment: This is command executed on the client puppet machine(20.201.110.198) and its output: "#puppet agent --configprint server" returns "puppet.example.com" THis is command executed on the master puppet machine(20.201.110.196) and its output: "#puppet cert list --all" returns "+ "puppet" (E4:66:56:31:4A:D8:B6:52:F8:C7:90:35:A6:1B:CB:B7) + "puppet.example.com" (F6:13:CC:E9:D8:5D:0A:E8:63:AD:DC:F8:7D:B4:02:FC) (alt names: "DNS:puppet", "DNS:puppet.example.com") " Again this is executed in the master puppet machine(20.201.110.196) and its output: "#facter fqdn" rturns "puppet.example.com"

Comment: @FelixFrank , I had given my outputs, would you please review it and reply for some possible solutions

Answer (score 3):

The master lost your CSR at some point. The easiest way from here will likely be to generate a new key and CSR on your agent machine, submit and sign that.

On the agent, do

1. `rm -r /var/lib/puppet/ssl` to get rid of obsolete certificate request data
2. `puppet agent --test` (output should indicate new CSR being generated)

It should then be possible to sign the certificate on the master in the regular fashion.